# Unable to replicate sample_n results using constant seed across R versions

Tags: r, random, dplyr, version

I'm trying to replicate the sampling results from a script made in early January 2021. At the time, I forgot to record the R version and dplyr version I was using to create the sample. Now I have reinstalled R with the newest version of R (4.1.1) and dplyr (1.0.7) but I can't replicate my sampling results. I know that earlier R versions might use different RNGs, so I've tried to use `RNGversion()` to try out my seed with all versions of R but to no avail. This is not entirely surprising because I recall having used at least R 3.6.0, after which there shouldn't have been changes to the default RNG.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(dplyr)
RNGversion("3.5.0")
set.seed(182508)
```

Are there any other factors besides the R version that could affect my randomization results? For example, changes in the dplyr function `sample_n`? I know that sample_n has been superseded by `slice_sample`, but `sample_n` is still usable in the newest version of dplyr.

Comment: I believe `sample.int` changed in R-4, meaning the same seed for sampling *integers* would produce different results between R-3.5 and R-4.0 (and later). But that's already encompassed in your *"besides the R version"*. I don't know that `dplyr::` functions would differ.